# No specs found error in webdriverio/appium

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, appium

I want to write test cases for mobile automation with appium using vscode and webdriverio and mocha.

I have downloaded the packages needed but whenever I run the command

```
wdio config
```

to run any test cases, I get the following error message:

[image]

this is my capabilities:

[image: capabilities]

my package.json file:

[image: package .json file]

and this is the test case I am trying to run:

[image: test case]

I have been following [a YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/XXaxOL-6gPA)
and these are the versions of node.js and appium I am using:

[image: versions]

I have included this in my wdio.config.js file but i still got the same error message

[image]

I was expecting to see the app open and close in my phone. since i am using a real device to test, but I got an error message that I have attached above

Comment: Welcome to SO! Whenever possible, please use raw text instead of images, as it is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Wdio.config.js" file mention the right file path. For example: './specs/*.js'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).